# When would you use "er" or "sie" instead of "es", specifically with the meaning of "it"?

Tags: english-to-german, pronoun, gender

I answered the translation of ***"Is it not your jacket"***, as ***"Sie ist nicht deine Jacke"***.

Duolingo marked this wrong.  Am I indeed wrong, or is this an error in the accepted answer?

I know that I have definitely seen "er/sie" used as "it".  Are there cases when feminine and masculine nouns are referred to only with es?

[image: My wrong answer from Duolingo]

I checked this source: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Grammar/Pronouns but since it is just a table with generic descriptions, it was unable to explain to me why a native speaker would or would not select a masculine or feminine pronoun for a masculine or feminine object rather than the neuter reference in standard conversation as the equivalent of the word "it" in English.

Comment: At least related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46736/es-ist-instead-of-der-sie-ist

Comment: *Is it not your jacket?* → *Ist es nicht deine Jacke?* — *It is not your jacket.* → *Es ist nicht deine Jacke.*

Comment: @Janka According to my understanding from what my friend told me, if it were a question and you know the thing *is a jacket* then it would be, "Ist sie nicht deine Jacke?", **would it not?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Es ist" instead of "der/sie ist"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46736/es-ist-instead-of-der-sie-ist)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Auf die Frage

> Ist das deine Jacke?

ist die im Deutschen übliche Antwortformulierung:

> Nein, das ist nicht meine Jacke.

Wenn du "Sie ist nicht meine Jacke" sagst, erkennt jeder, dass du Deutsch erst lernst und die üblichen Ausdrucksformen noch nicht sicher beherrschst.

Diese Ausdrucksform mit "das" gilt sogar, wenn es um Menschen geht:

> Ist das deine Tante?
>
> Nein, das ist nicht meine Tante.

Allerdings würdest du, wenn die Person, um die es geht, dabei ist, veilleicht versuchen, das "das" zu umgehen, um die Gefahr einer Beleidigung zu vermeiden. Dann würdest du vielleicht etwas umständlicher sagen:

> Aber nein, diese Dame ist nicht meine Tante.

Der Grund für die Wahl des "das" ist übrigens einfach: Schon im Fragesatz wurde ja auf den Gegenstand, um den es geht, mit "das" verwiesen.

Anders ist es, wenn im Fragesatz kein "das" vorkommt:

> Hast du deine Jacke schon von der Reinigung geholt?
>
> Nein, ich habe sie noch nicht von der Reinigung geholt.

Comment: Also, würden ein Deutscher gar nie sagen, "Sie ist nicht deine Jacke"?

Comment: @RyanMortensen Ja

Comment: *„Ich habe neulich Anna gesehen. Ist sie eigentlich deine Tante?“ - „Ja, sie ist meine Tante“* seems like a pretty normal exchange.

Comment: @Narusan.  Yes, your example is correct. But as soon as somebody points at your aunt and says: "Ist **das** deine Tante?" the answer is invariably "Ja, **das** ist meine Tante."

Comment: @RyanMortensen  Ja, einem im deutschsprachigen Raum aufgewachsenen Menschen würde so ein Satz normalerweise nicht über die Lippen kommen. Ausnahmen in der Dichtkunst oder sonstigen sprachlichen Sondersituationen können natürlich vorkommen.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser & ChristianGeiselmann: Sollte man nicht eine verneinte Fragen mit "Nein" oder "Doch" antworten?

Comment: I don’t understand what all this about _das_ has to do with the question. There is no _das_, explicit or implicit, in the Duolingo sentence. The sentence to be translated is “**It** is not your jacket”, not “**That** is not your jacket”. You wouldn’t use _das_ at all in a German version, so why is _das_ the basis of the answer here?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet stimmt, man würde den satz auch nicht wirklich so sagen. "Das" statt "es" ist viel natürlicher.

Comment: @Christian Your absolutism is utterly unwarranted. I’ll grant that “das”/”es” is more common here but “sie” is grammatical, and entirely fine, in both your examples. It simply means that the answerer does not grammatically refer back to the definite article in the question but rather directly to the subject.

Answer (score 11):

I checked with a friend who is a German.  This was the answer I received:

If you are saying "This (*thing* that isn't a jacket) is not your jacket" = "Es / Das (Ding) ist nicht deine Jacke"...

...or...

If you are saying "This (*particular* jacket) is not *your* jacket" = "Sie / Die (Jacke) ist nicht deine Jacke"

Comment: Your friend told you right. In addition, the *es/das* variant is also used if the fact **ist nicht** is the most important thing to take note of. So people would **almost always** say *Das ist nicht deine Jacke.* if you accidentally took theirs.

Comment: @Janka Oh, okay.  Wouldn't that basically be changing the translation from "*It* is..." to "*That* is..." ?  In that scenario, I would imagine that some hand gesture such as a pointing would be included in tandem with the statement.

Comment: See Christian's answer.

Answer (score 3):

"Sie ist nicht deine Jacke." is correct but unusual.
It gives quite some importance to the jacket, that a jacket does not usually have.

> "Ich würde gerne Elvis Jacke tragen." - "Sie ist nicht Deine Jacke."

So you would only hear this construction for jackets that have their own names or are up for auction at Sotheby's.
It makes a difference, once the jacket is introduced before:

> "Ich würde dich die Jacke tragen lassen, aber sie ist nicht deine Jacke."

Answer (score 2):

"Sie" is the <del>reflexive</del> personal pronoun referring to the jacket. "Jacke" is feminine, so it must be "sie". If you're referring to a generic thing in general, you can also use "es" in some situations (see below).

However, "Sie ist nicht deine Jacke" is not proper German. You could instead say (figuratively pointing at it) "dies ist nicht deine Jacke" (because it's either someone else's or it's not even a jacket) or (from a selection of jackets) "*diese* ist nicht *deine* Jacke". Or - to emphasize the non-ownership - "Diese Jacke gehört nicht dir".

Comment: It's not reflexive, it's a personal pronoun.

Comment: Thx @Eller, that's correct(ed).